# Не добавляется товар в корзину

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, корзина

появилась проблема на сайте на Wordpress. Когда я зарегистрирован на сайте в корзину товары вообще не добавляются. Если же я не зарегистрирован, то добавляется только один товар  и все.
Никаких ошибок нет. Все плагины помимо Woocommerce отключал, кэш чистил, все равно не помогает. Что делать?

Comment: С таким описание проблемы надо обращаться к телепатам. А ошибки есть. Просто надо научиться их смотреть.

Comment: Ну подскажите тогда как я могу их посмотреть?

Comment: Одни в логах на сервере другие в консоли браузера.

Comment: На моем хосте не отображаться логи. Единственное что смог найти это вызов "wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments" после добавления товара в корзину, после которого корзина становится путая.

Comment: "не отображаются логи"...ппц.. Рано тебе с такими знаниями заниматься сайтостроением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалось в том что полетела структура таблицы wp_woocommerce_sessions.
Удалил таблицу, импортировал структуру с другого сайта и все заработало.